# Show set of all $n \times n$ matrices with determinant equal to $1$ forms a subgroup of a general linear group

Tags: matrices, group-theory, determinant

Show set of all $n \times n$ matrices with determinant equal to $1$ forms a subgroup of the general linear group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

In the question above, I am stuck on how to proceed. I know that the formula that I need to use at some point is $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the set of all $n \times n$ matrices witt $\det =1$.

You have to show:

If $A,B \in G$, then $AB \in G$ and $A^{-1} \in G$.

If $A,B \in G$, then $\det(AB)=x$ and $\det(A^{-1})=y$.

If you can show that $x=y=1$, then you are done !

Comment: Ah thanks! What should I use for A and B?

Comment: I used {{3,2},{4,3}} and {{4,1},{7,2}}

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subset of $G$, then $H$ is a subgroup if and only if

- For each $h_1,h_2\in H$, the element $h_1h_2$ is also in $H$
- For each $h\in H$, the element $h^{-1}$ is also in $H$.

That's where you start. At the definition.

You can also use the fact that in your case, an element $A$ (a matrix) is in $H$ if and only if $\det(A)=1$.